# Rigorous QFT from integration over subspace

Tags: measure-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

Many perturbative QFTs suffer from the lack of a rigorous
definition of a "good enough" measure over the space of paths (or
fields) $P$,

$$\mathcal{Z} = \int_{{x \in P}} e^{iS(x)} Dx$$

There are many ways to "fix" this. For example, if the gauge
group $G$ is big and good enough, one could instead work with the (hopefully finite dimensional) quotient space
$P/G$. However this does not work for all cases. **I'm
wondering if there are approaches that work for suitable subspace
$P' \subset P$?**

For example, instead of working with all continuous
paths, work with piecewise linear paths or paths in Schwartz space (smooth and tamed).

Comment: Well, a lattice field theory (which is perfectly rigorous, at least in finite volume) can be understood as being formulated in terms of piecewise linear paths, so I suppose the answer is "yes" as posed ... although I wonder if that's what you had in mind.